# Como fazer a função keydown funcionar com o programa em segundo plano?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Código:

```
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F7)
    {
        A1 = !A1;
    }
```

Como fazer para este código funcionar sem o programa estar em primeiro plano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem registrar uma tecla global no Windows. Eu peguei uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413314/221800) com o que deve fazer:

Importe as funções da Win32:

```
// DLL libraries used to manage hotkeys
[DllImport("user32.dll")] 
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);
```

Determine o ID da tecla que deseja manipular:

```
const int MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID = 1;
```

Registre a tecla já no construtor do formulário principal:

```
// Modifier keys codes: Alt = 1, Ctrl = 2, Shift = 4, Win = 8
// Compute the addition of each combination of the keys you want to be pressed
// ALT+CTRL = 1 + 2 = 3 , CTRL+SHIFT = 2 + 4 = 6...
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID, 6, (int) Keys.F12);
```

Cria o método que receberá a mensagem do Windows para escolher o que fazer:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
    if (m.Msg == 0x0312 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == MYACTION_HOTKEY_ID) {
        // My hotkey has been typed

        // Do what you want here
        // ...
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/ProcKey.cs).